# How to import an angular2 project inside another angular2 project without overwriting the routes of the second project?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm having some troubles importing an angular2 project "project1" inside another angular2 project "project2". I want when the project2 runs to redirect it to Login2Component which is specified in my AppRoutingViewsModule but actually is redirecting to LoginComponent  which is specified in the routes inside the first project. Here are my routing files and also the app.module where I import the first project into the second project.

***AppRoutingModule project1***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { AppAuthGuard } from "./security/app-auth-guard.component";
import { NoAuthComponent } from '../app/layouts/no-auth/no-auth.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from '../app/layouts/not-found/notfound.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { SsvmnComponent } from './ssvmn.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }, 
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,canActivate: [AppAuthGuard],
     children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
        { path: 'ssvmn/:comp', component: SsvmnComponent }
     ]
    },
    { path: 'no-auth', component: NoAuthComponent },
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

***AppRoutingViewsModule project2***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Login2Component } from './login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login2', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login2', component: Login2Component }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingViewsModule { }
```

***App module project2***

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponentsModule } from 'sigma-web';
import { AppRoutingViewsModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Login2Component } from './login.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Login2Component
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppComponentsModule,
    AppRoutingViewsModule
],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Let me know if you need more information.
Thanks.

**Solution:**

It's not overwriting it. It merges the routes and then picks the first path that matches the route. So it basically ignores any paths that look to be duplicates. And if you have a wildcard path in the merged set of paths, all paths after the wildcard path are ignored because the router will pick the wildcard path
Credits: DeborahK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
],
```

Merges the routes from the two components. So you then have:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login2', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'login2', component: Login2Component }
```

Since routing order matters and the router always goes with the first match, an empty (default) route will always go to the login path.

If you could provide more information on what exactly you are trying to accomplish, we may be able to provide more information on how to achieve it.

Depending on what you are trying to do, a "parent" route may help to distinquish between the two sets of routes.

Comment: Hi, I added more information to my routing files, basically what I want to do is use the empty route of my second project but I'm not able to do it, I  try to delete the empty route of my first project but when I did that the app redirects my  to this route:  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }. It seems like the first route is overwriting the second one.

Comment: It's not overwriting it. It *merges* the routes and then picks the first path that matches the route. So it basically ignores any paths that look to be duplicates. And if you have a wildcard path in the merged set of paths, all paths after the wildcard path are ignored because the router will pick the wildcard path.

Comment: Glad that helped. If you could mark this as your answer, that will close this question. Thanks!